# How to run a script on a service container in Gitlab CI

Tags: gitlab-ci

I'm doing e2e testing using Cypress in Gitlab CI. I imported database and backend as services. Now I need to run an npm script on backend to populate the db. How do I do that?

```
.docker: &docker
  tags:
    - docker
    
t:test-server-mr:
  stage: test
  allow_failure: true
  before_script:
    - echo "Skipping global before script"
  image: node:12.16.1-stretch
  services:
    - name: registry.gitlab.com/registryname/backend/db:latest
      alias: database
    - name: registry.gitlab.com/registryname/backend/master
      alias: backend
  script:
    - npm install
    - npm run ci
  <<: [*docker]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add another entry under the `script` property:

```
  script:
    - npm install
    - npm run ci
    - npm run init_my_db
```